# Giant Overdrive 2 fork replacement

Tags: mountain-bike

I have a 2014 Giant Trance with an Overdrive 2 tapered steerer (1-1/2 - 1-1/4). As we know, the standard tapered steerer is 1-1/2 - 1-1/8 inch. I want to replace my OEM fork (Fox 32 Float Evolution CTD 140) with a more advanced Fox or RS. Is it possible to fit the bike with a standard steerer? I know that it would mean changing all the front end of the bike (fork, headset, stem) which I am prepared to do. Is there a headset to accommodate my frame and new fork. Would a standard tapered integrated headset do? Has anyone have an OD2 Giant bike here that have done the same exercise? This bike is problematic!

Answer (score 2):

You can just buy a standard tapered headset. Or if you can firnt it, only the upper assembly for 1 1/8". Giant uses the same diamete for their 1 1/8" and 1 1/4" headsets as it says here: http://www.pinkbike.com/news/Giant-OverDrive-2-Steerer-tube-sizing-2011.html.

Another solution I can think of is to turn a spacer yourself (or have it done by someone) to work as an inner race for the bearing. It's more demanding (since you would have to turn both the spacer and a cap), but could probably work out a bit cheaper than the entire headset.

Answer (score -1):

the Cane Creek 40 Series ZS44 Zero Stack Tapered Conversion Headset seems like it would get the job done.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  We generally don't get involved with specific product recommendations, partially because the site is global, and not all products are available everywhere.  Also new products tend to have a short availability window before they're replaced.  However you're answering the question posed.  Do you have a link to the item ?  Have you used it or one similar?  What were your experiences?    Remember the question was asked 12 months ago, so OP may have solved their problem, but google will send others here too.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider expanding your answer to explain how this particular headset solves the OP's problem. Specifically, what features of this headset make it a good solution? A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.